# Toad: assign a result of a query to a variable as string

Tags: sql, select, sqlplus, toad

I'm working with Toad and I'm trying to do something with its Editor.
Imagine that we can do the query below in an Editor of Toad:
`select firstName from Name`

And the output:
**firstName**
aa
 bb
 cc

What I need now is to generate a string variable as below with these first name:
`aa,bb,cc`

And finally print this variable into the output window.

I've tried some methods such as `SET result = select firstName from Name`, but I always fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for listagg().  To put it into a variable you'll want to SELECT INTO:

```
SQL> with name(firstname) as (
     select 'aa' from dual union
     select 'bb' from dual union
     select 'cc' from dual
   )
   select listagg(firstname, ',')
     within group (order by firstname) name_list
   from name;

NAME_LIST
--------------------------------------------------
aa,bb,cc

SQL>
```

EDIT:  Made generic to apply to your own table.

```
select listagg(your_column, ',')
         within group (order by your_column,) list_format
       from your_table;
```

Comment: I have about 1000 firstNames... Can we avoid `select` one by one?

Comment: You only need the code from the select listagg() on down.  The WITH part is to set up the example to show how it works. Its called a common table expression (CTE) and is like an in-line temp table. I have to question that value of 1000 names in a comma separated list though?  What is the real goal?  Perhaps there is a better way to get to the end result you are really after. Oracle has a size limit of 4000 for a varchar2() datatype if you intend on loading the result into a variable.